# Dynamically change other content when clicking on a tab

Tags: wordpress

I'm updating my WordPress website which is using Thrive Themes. I want to change the content displayed in another section of my page whenever a tab is clicked.

This image visualizes what I'm trying to explain:

[image: Screenshot of the tabbed interface]

For whatever reason I can't figure out how this is done in Thrive Themes. Are there any other good plugins available that does this basic job?

Alternatively, while I'd prefer using a plugin, knowing other programming languages I'd presume this isn't hard at all to code (but I never programmed a website, so I may be wrong). So if you have a simple suggestions for how I code it I'd appreciate that also.

Grateful for any help!